# How do i prevent Apple form rejecting my app based on screen size?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, macos

My app developed in React Native runs on iPhone 6 and above (all the way through to the iPhone 12 Pro Max using iOS 14.1).

Getting my apps components, images etc... to drop down to accommodate the screen size of the iPhone SE, 5 and 5s is proving damn near impossible. I know the SE is currently receiving the latest iOS updates (my SE device for example runs the latest iOS 14.2), so it seems supported, but i don't know about 5, 5s. Either way it's really not something i want to develop for.

If i submitted the app to the app market, is there a strong chance of it being rejected on the basis of not supporting the iPhone SE which has a logical `width: 320 & height: 568` ?

Comment: Come on, supporting screen sizes is not that hard... Just learn about auto layout.

Comment: This question is still *opinion based*. Either submit your app and see what happens or make your app work on all supported devices (which is the right thing to do).  You can't "prevent" Apple from rejecting your app except by complying with their guidelines.